# How to groupby on level 1 and rank on another level with multi indexing in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, performance, pandas-groupby

I want to group by one level index and rank another index. I am trying to this on index because it will take less time.

```
data_list = [['tom', 10,16], ['nick', 15,19], ['juli', 14,11],['tom',19, 15],['tom', 50,19]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list,columns = ["name","time","age"])
```

[image]

This is what I am trying to do but including time in rank. as my database is pretty huge I will be doing same process again and again.

```
df.index  = df["name"]
df = df[df.groupby(df.index)['time'].rank() == 1]
```

Expected output

[image]

what if I set both Name and time at index

```
df.set_index(["name","time"],inplace = True)
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you calculate a rank on a group and take the element with rank 1, then you want to take the first per group? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Also, do you expect your index to have duplicates? If not, your `df.groupby(df.index)['time'].rank()` command will be 1s only.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) method on your groups to take the first element of each group:

```
df.groupby('name').first()
```

output:

```
      time  age
name           
juli    14   11
nick    15   19
tom     10   16
```

If your elements are sorted by increasing time, the lowest time will be kept.

Add the `sort=False` parameter to `groupby` to keep the original order:

```
>>> df.groupby('name', sort=False).first()
      time  age
name           
tom     10   16
nick    15   19
juli    14   11
```

Comment: Probably you didn't understand my question. I want to rank on time and group by name, But both I want to it on index as it would be less costly.

Comment: Can you provide a better example? What is giving you an issue here?

Comment: @NiraliKhoda do you want to keep the lowest `time` per group? If yes, just make sure the dataframe is sorted by time first (`df = df.sort_values(by='time')`) and apply my method.

Comment: I have to do whole process ~1000 time per loop. so What I am trying to is that, If I keep both name and time in index It will decrease the time but if I keep it in index . I am able to group by like this "df.groupby(df.index)" but how to rank time ?

Comment: Well, as I said what you want to achieve is not clear to me. (I said, "what", not "how")

Comment: df = df[df.groupby(df.index)['time'].rank() == 1] basically I want to further optimize the time if it is possible

Comment: Well, I am sincerely sorry, you are not describing the "what". Also, if you have a non duplicate index `df[df.groupby(df.index)['time'].rank() == 1]` is doing nothing…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235456/discussion-between-nirali-khoda-and-mozway).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with your code?

```
>>> df[df.groupby('name')['time'].rank().eq(1)]

   name  time  age
0   tom    10   16
1  nick    15   19
2  juli    14   11
```